# Matching JSON object with an instance

Tags: java, unit-testing, jsonpath

Assume I have following DTO:

```
class C {
    String a;
    String b;
}
```

And I have the JSON:

```
{
    "c" : {
        "a" : "aaa",
        "b" : "bbb"
    }
}
```

What I want to do is, accomplish following test:

```
C expected = new C("aaa","bbb");
mockMvc.perform(get("url"))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.c", is(expected)));
```

It fails. If I first serialize `expected` to JSON and then try to match, it again fails because it's a string. Is this possible?

Comment: your JSON is not valid. `=` should be `:`

Comment: You could take a look to the jackson library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always remember: There is no such thing as a "JSON object". JSON is a serialization format for objects. JSON is always a string. You can convert from object to JSON and back (and hence from object to string and back). But

```
{ "a": "b" }
```

is a JavaScript object, not JSON (even if it looks very similar).

This in fact is the answer to your question: When you serialize `expected`, you get JSON (the transport format, i.e. the string). This isn't what `jsonPath()` checks. `jsonPath()` validates against JavaScript types.

[This blog post](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/integration-testing-of-spring-mvc-applications-write-clean-assertions-with-jsonpath/) suggests that you need to check each field individually:

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.c.a", is(expected.a)))
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.c.b", is(expected.b)));
```

which is tedious. What you need is

a) to configure your JSON framework to use a mapping system that sorts keys and

b) you need to figure out what type `jsonPath("$.c", ...)` returns - it's probably the type which your JSON framework uses to represent generic JavaScript objects.

The check then looks like this:

```
C c = new C("aaa","bbb");
String serialized = JSON.serialize(c); // to string
JSObject expected = JSON.parse(serialized); // to generic JavaScript object
mockMvc.perform(get("url"))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.c", is(expected)));
```

Note that this only works if `JSObject` has a proper implementation for `equals()`.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. I thought the same thing, just couldn't find the matching class. And this is ugly as hell.

Comment: Which JSON framework do you use? If you can't find it, set a breakpoint inside of `is()` where the values are compared.

Comment: I meant I didn't know until your answer :) Jackson parses the response into `LinkedHashMap`, so serializing and deserializing after works properly, as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford to modify your "C" class to add it an "equals" operator and to modify slightly your JSON file, I would suggest you to transform your JSON string into an instance of "C". This can be done with a good JSON-ifier (Jackson or GSON). Then you just have to compare the 2 instances.
Some examples with GSON:

```
class C {
    String a;
    String b;
    public boolean equals(C obj) { return a.equals(obj.a) && b.equals(obj.b); }
}
// Your JSON file should look like that
{
    "a" : "aaa",
    "b" : "bbb"
}
// So the test is simple
C expected = new C("aaa","bbb");
C json = gson.fromJson(jsonString, C.class); 
if (expected.equals(json)) {
    // Do whatever you want here
}
```

If you cannot afford to change the JSON file, just create another class to contains your main class, like this:

```
class Wrapper {
    C c;
}
Wrapper jsonW = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Wrapper.class);
C json = jsonW.c;
...
```

If you cannot afford the addition of the equals operator, I suggest to create JSON string based on the 2 "C" instance objects and compare the strings. Your jsonString becomes a real "C" object (json) before ending into a new string (jsonStr).

```
String expectedStr = gson.toJson(expected);
String jsonStr = gson.toJSON(json);
if (expectedStr.equals(jsonStr)) {
    // Do whatever you want here
}
```

Comment: If I didn't need to use `JsonPath`, this would be the right answer.